# Exporting data frames to Excel using write.xls using Windows 7 (using R)

Tags: python, r, file-io, dataframe, export-to-excel

I am trying to export a bunch of data frames to excel using the `write.xls` function in R

Desired Outcome: The selected data frames should be exported to R

```
Error Message: [1] "Does 'python' exist, and is it in the path?"
```

Reproducible Code:

```
purchase_year <- c(2007,2007,2007,2008,2008,2008,2009,2009,2009,2009,2009)
sold_year <- c(2007,2008,2009,2009,2010,2011,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013)
units <-c(1,4,4,8,3,1,3,1,1,0,2)
df <- data.frame(purchase_year,sold_year,units)


library(dataframes2xls)
  write.xls(df,"C:/WORK/OUTPUT.xls", sh.names = "default", formats = "default",
            t.formats = FALSE,  fnt.metr = "default",
            col.widths = 48, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,
            to.floats = "default",  python = "python", 
            py.script = "default", sh.return = FALSE)
```

Other Information:

1. I am working on a 32bit windows 7 machine
2. Installed Python 3.2.2 as well
3. went through the documentation of write.xls
4. Did try my best looking up this and the other forums
5. Tried including the URL of the python 'exe' in the python argument, that dint work either

Since I'll be writing out multiple sheets across multiple worksheets, CSV does not look like an option at this point in time.

Thanks to all your help, the issue has been **RESOLVED**

**SOLUTION**

1. Ensuring that the correct version of Python is installed. *dataframes2xls* is designed to work with Python 2.x. I used 2.7.5
2. Python installation in my system was not accessible to R. I tried the steps outlined by David Marx which I am quoting  here: *Try going to the command prompt and running the command python. If this returns an error, you need to add the path to the python executable to your PATH environment variable: computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm*

Comment: There are other options for writing Excel files, the most popular being **xlsx** and **XLConnect** packages.

Comment: Thanks @joran will try those as well

Comment: @joran Will it be possible to demonstrate how to do this using xlsx?

Comment: Yes. The package author has demonstrated it nicely in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code. Im running Centos though. It worked fine after I changed the output file name to just "Output.xls". Seems like either a windows problem, or perhaps you don't have python/R configured properly.

Comment: I tried installing a different version of python and its throwing up the same error. Any pointers on configuring python?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this package, but I'd bet the problem is that it's designed for python 2.x, not python 3.x (which is a slightly different language). Try installing python 2.7. You may need to uninstall your current python 3.x

Comment: I tried with Python 2.4.x and 2.7.5, and I am still getting the same error. Is there a need to specify the python version in the function argument? Any pointers on configuring python?

Comment: Try going to the command prompt and running the command `python`. If this returns an error, you need to add the path to the python executable to your PATH environment variable: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: @RaamaVi I see you're new here: welcome to the community! When a posted answer resolves your issue, you should "accept" that answer. There's a checkbox below the answer score you can click. You should accept a response here and in the other question you posted. This does several things: it alerts the community that you're issue has been resolved, it directs future people with the same problem to the answer that resolved the issue, and it increases the SO "reputation" for both you and the person who responded.